# Insert operation triggering NOT(ISNEW())

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, after-trigger

I would like to ask for help regarding why an insert operation would trigger and fail this validation rule:

```
AND(NOT(ISNEW()), ISPICKVAL(Pipeline_Type__c,'Licence'), ISBLANK(Related_Pipeline__c))
```

The error message I get is:

```
AutoCreateSubPipeline: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation rule: Please add licence-maintenance related pipeline: [Related_Pipeline__c] Class.SubPipelineAutoCreator.runProcess: line 30, column 1 Trigger.AutoCreateSubPipeline: line 9, column 1
```

The Apex code referenced in the error message are as belows:

When I create a pipeline, I want to create its sub-pipelines.

```
trigger AutoCreateSubPipeline on Pipeline__c (after insert, after update) {
   SubPipelineAutoCreator creator = SubPipelineAutoCreator.getInstance();
   for (Pipeline__c newPl : Trigger.new) {
      Pipeline__c oldPl = null;
      if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
         oldPl = Trigger.oldMap.get(newPl.id);
      }
      creator.runProcess(oldPl, newPl);
   }
}
```

This is the Apex class containing the logic for creating sub-pipelines. The error message refers to the `upsert listSpl` line in this class.

```
public class SubPipelineAutoCreator {

   private static SubPipelineAutoCreator instance = null;

   private SubPipelineAutoCreator() {}

   public static SubPipelineAutoCreator getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new SubPipelineAutoCreator();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public void runProcess(Pipeline__c oldPl, Pipeline__c newPl) {
      List<Sub_Pipeline__c> listSpl =
         [select id from Sub_Pipeline__c where Pipeline_Project_Name__c = :newPl.Id order by Allocation_Month__c];
      if (oldPl!=null) {
         if (mustRefreshSubPipeline(oldPl, newPl)) {
            delete listSpl;
            listSpl = [select id from Sub_Pipeline__c where Pipeline_Project_Name__c = :newPl.Id order by Allocation_Month__c];
         }
      }

      if (listSpl.size()==0) {
         if (newPl.Recurring__c != null) {
            listSpl = processRecurring(newPl);
         } else {
            listSpl.add(createSingleSPL(newPl, newPl.Name, newPl.Allocation_Month__c, 1, false));
         }
         upsert listSpl;
      }
   }

   // Refresh SPL if one or more of the following changes:
   // 1. State of recurring in PL (yes>no or no>yes)
   // 2. Either/both of term from or term to
   // 3. R&C figures
   private boolean mustRefreshSubPipeline(Pipeline__c oldPl, Pipeline__c newPl) {
      boolean result = false;
      boolean hasBecomeNonRecurring = (oldPl.Recurring__c!=null) && (newPl.Recurring__c==null);
      boolean hasBecomeRecurring = (oldPl.Recurring__c==null) && (newPl.Recurring__c!=null);

      Date oldFrom = oldPl.Term_From__c;
      Date oldTo = oldPl.Term_To__c;
      Date newFrom = newPl.Term_From__c;
      Date newTo = newPl.Term_To__c;
      boolean isFromChanged = false;
      boolean isToChanged = false;
      if (oldFrom!=null && oldTo!=null && newFrom!=null && newTo!=null) {
         DateTime oldFromDt = DateTime.newInstance(oldFrom.year(),oldFrom.month(),oldFrom.day());
         Datetime oldToDt = DateTime.newInstance(oldTo.year(),oldTo.month(),oldTo.day());
         Datetime newFromDt = DateTime.newInstance(newFrom.year(),newFrom.month(),newFrom.day());
         Datetime newToDt = DateTime.newInstance(newTo.year(),newTo.month(),newTo.day());
         isFromChanged = oldFromDt.format('MMMyyyy').compareTo(newFromDt.format('MMMyyyy'))!=0;
         isToChanged = oldToDt.format('MMMyyyy').compareTo(newToDt.format('MMMyyyy'))!=0;
      }

      boolean isIntCostSame =
         (newPl.Internal_Cost__c == null && oldPl.Internal_Cost__c == null) ||
         (newPl.Internal_Cost__c != null && oldPl.Internal_Cost__c != null && newPl.Internal_Cost__c == oldPl.Internal_Cost__c);
      boolean isRCChanged = 
         newPl.Quotation__c != oldPl.Quotation__c ||
         newPl.External_Cost__c != oldPl.External_Cost__c ||
         !isIntCostSame;

      result = hasBecomeNonRecurring || hasBecomeRecurring|| isFromChanged || isToChanged || isRCChanged;

      return result;
   }

   private Integer numberOfMonths(Date termFrom, Date termTo) {
      Integer numMonths = 1;
      if (termFrom != null && termTo != null) {
         numMonths = termFrom.monthsBetween(termTo) + 1;
      }
      return numMonths;
   }

   private List<Sub_Pipeline__c> processRecurring(Pipeline__c pl) {
      Integer numMonths = numberOfMonths(pl.Term_From__c, pl.Term_To__c);
      Date termFrom = pl.Term_From__c;

      List<Sub_Pipeline__c> listSpl = new List<Sub_Pipeline__c>();
      for (Integer i=0; i<numMonths; i++) {
         Datetime d = termFrom.addMonths(i);
         String splName = pl.Name + ' - ' + d.format('MMM yy');
         Sub_Pipeline__c spl = createSingleSPL(pl, splName, d.date(), numMonths, (i==(numMonths-1)));
         listSpl.add(spl);
      }

      return listSpl;
   }

   private Sub_Pipeline__c createSingleSPL(Pipeline__c pl, String name, Date allocMth, Integer numMonths, Boolean isLastMonth) {
      Sub_Pipeline__c spl = new Sub_Pipeline__c();
      spl.Pipeline_Project_Name__c = pl.id;
      spl.Name = name;
      spl.Quotation__c = divide(pl.Quotation__c, numMonths, isLastMonth);
      spl.External_Cost__c = divide(pl.External_Cost__c, numMonths, isLastMonth);

      if (pl.OwnerId != null) {
         spl.Owner__c = pl.OwnerId;
      }
      if (pl.Related_Pipeline__c != null) {
         spl.License_Maintenace_related_pipeline__c = pl.Related_Pipeline__c;
      }
      if (pl.External_Cost_USD__c != null) {
         spl.External_Cost_USD__c = divide(pl.External_Cost_USD__c, numMonths, isLastMonth);
      }
      if (pl.Internal_Cost__c != null) {
         spl.Internal_Cost__c = divide(pl.Internal_Cost__c, numMonths, isLastMonth);
      }

      return spl;
   }

   private Decimal divide(Decimal value, Integer divisor, Boolean isLastMonth) {
      Integer upval = (Integer)(value * 100);
      Integer subres = upval / divisor;
      if (isLastMonth) subres += Math.mod(upval, divisor);
      return (1.0 * subres) / 100;
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems your validation rule is on the object `Sub_Pipeline__c` and the trigger is on the object `Pipeline__c`, or are they on the same object. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Hi @HemantJain both the validation rule and the trigger are on `Pipeline__c`.

Comment: Then, is there any rollup summary field on `Pipeline__c` object, which will be updated after the `upsert listSpl` statement. Rollup summary updates can cause validation rules to fire again.

Comment: Try AND ((ISNEW() = False), ISPICKVAL(Pipeline_Type__c,'Licence'), ISBLANK(Related_Pipeline__c))

Comment: @HemantJain You are right, there are a few rollup summary fields on `Pipeline__c` that tallies up revenue figures on the related `Sub_Pipeline__c` objects!

Comment: So this might be the cause. The validation rule is getting fired after the roll up update